# How to load theme textdomain from plugin?

Tags: translation, localization

I built a simple localization plugin to suit some specifications needed by my orgnanization. For each language there is a single .mo file  that contains both the theme translations as the page content translations. The .mo files are located in  `myplugin/languages/en_US.mo`. I'm trying to use these .mo files for all gettext calls however I cannot get them to work.

Here is the code I'm using to load the text domain:

```
echo get_locale(); // es_ES
$directory = dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)) . '/lang/';
load_plugin_textdomain('localization-v', false, $directory); 
_e("English");
```

Comment: Curiously from quick look I don't see why would theme version not work for plugin. Note that unless in your example if run verbatim your echo will run before text domain is really loaded and single underscore is wrong function.

Answer (score 5):

You are completely loading your language file wrong in your plugin, and your file naming is also wrong.

```
load_theme_textdomain('my_plugin', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/languages');
```

should be

```
load_plugin_textdomain('my_plugin', false, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)) . '/lang/');
```

Also, your mo and po files should be named `my_plugin-en_US.mo` and `my_plugin-en_US.po`. Go have a look at [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-localize-wordpress-themes-and-plugins--wp-22779) also, this will help you out a lot.

Comment: Damn, the naming PLUGINNAME-en_EN.mo was key to my issue. Thanks for that hint!